# Write power of 2 in sphinx documentation

Tags: python, python-sphinx, numpydoc

I try to write power of 2 but I get something strange.

```
def cal_xy(X, Y):
    """

    Parameters
    ----------
    X : np.ndarray, shape=(2\ :sup:`n`, 2\ :sup:`n`)
    Y : np.ndarray, shape=(2\ :sup:`n`, n)

    Returns
    -------
    xy : np.ndarray, shape=(n, 2\ :sup:`n`)
    """
    return (Y.T).dot(X)
```

Result:

**Parameters: X** : *np.ndarray, shape=(2\ <sup>n</sup>, 2<sup>n</sup>)*

The first superscript is wrong. I don't want any slash or space between 2 and n.

Comment: Not reproducible when I `make html`. It generates code `X : np.ndarray, shape=(2<sup>n</sup>, 2<sup>n</sup>)`.

Comment: But that is what I see now. I'm using numpydoc instead of napoleon extension of sphinx. Don't know if that would make a difference.

Comment: Made a default sphinx setup(ran `sphinx-quickstart` and left everything as default) and added your code (Three lines starting with Parameters) at the end of index.rst. Ran `make html` and there is `<p>X : np.ndarray, shape=(2<sup>n</sup>, 2<sup>n</sup>)</p>` generated in index.html. Do you get the same results when you follow these steps?

Comment: When I put it in index.rst, it works. But when I put it in the docstring of a function, it doesn't work.

Comment: It is a problem of `numpydoc`. `sphinx.ext.napoleon` parses the docstring correctly.